# Mathematics of Tetris 2.0

Tags: recreational-mathematics, problem-solving, packing-problem

Based on the question [The Mathematics of Tetris](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80246/the-mathematics-of-tetris), I was wondering if it is possible to have a series of tetris blocks that is impossible to clear. For example, getting the string TTTSS.. forces the player to lose even with best play.

Assuming that the tetris field is as usual, 20 high by 10 wide.

Comment: You should probably have a look at [Bastet](http://fph.altervista.org/prog/bastet.html)

Comment: When you say that the question is MoT 2.0, does that mean that with every substantial edit you will increase the version? Will there be alpha/beta/release candidate versions as well? :-)

Comment: @Asaf, that isn't for me to decide. I am sure others will have other questions that are similar in nature.

Comment: Is this for Tetris with the old randomizer or with the randomizer used since 2001?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

In the paper [How to lose at tetris](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.55.8562&rep=rep1&type=pdf), Heidi Burgiel shows that "the tetris game consisting of only $Z$-tetrominoes alternating orientation will always end before 70,000 tetrominoes have been played."  The paper also shows that a game with random play by the computer will end with probability one, because almost surely a sequence of 127,200 consecutive alternating $Z$-tetrominoes will eventually appear, and this forces the game to end from *any* position.

John Brzustowski had previously proved that the computer has a winning strategy.