# Can a $10\times 10$ square be entirely covered by 25 $T$-shape bricks?

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics, polyomino

Let $ABCD$ be a square in which length of a side is $10$ meters. Suppose that we have $T$-shape brick which consists of $4$ smaller squares in which a side of each smaller square has length of $1$ meter. Can $ABCD$ be entirely covered by 25 $T$-shape bricks?

I have tried but can not figure out where to start. Please give me some hints, not the full solution!

[image]

Comment: Use colouring proofs.

Comment: If the grid is coloured like a checkerboard, $25$ T-shapes can never cover the same number of black squares as red.

Comment: [Closely related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/80246/11619) (but not a dupe!)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Think to the given square as a $10\times 10$ chessboard with alternate black and white squares and assume that such covering with $T$ pieces exists.
Then each of the $25$ $T$ pieces will have 1) $3$ black squares and $1$ white square or 2) $3$ white squares and $1$ black square. Let $b$ the number of $T$ pieces of the first category and $w$ the number of $T$ pieces of the second category. Then the integers $b$ and $w$ should satisfy the following equations:
$$3b+w=\frac{10\cdot 10}{2},\quad b+3w=\frac{10\cdot 10}{2}.$$
What may we conclude?

**Bonus question**: What happens when the given square is $n\times n$?

Comment: Do you know the answer for the $m$-by-$n$ rectangular case?  It suffices that both $m$ and $n$ are divisible by $4$, but I cannot prove that this is necessary.  I know that one of $m$ and $n$ is divisible by $4$ (or better, just as you showed, $8\mid mn$).

Comment: @Batominovski Yes,  both $m$ and $n$ are divisible by 4 is also necessary. See  https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2313337.pdf?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents