# Tiling a 4 X 11 board.

Tags: combinatorics, packing-problem

Prove that a 4 x 11 rectangle cannot be tiled by L-shaped tetrominoes.
[image: Tiles]

Comment: I have no idea how to start the proof.

Comment: I can't resist linking to [this (mildly embarrassing for me) old thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/80246/11619).

Comment: But the question is in need of a bit of context as outlined in [our guide fore new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619) :-(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am considering a grid with $4$ column and $11$ rows. Now, color the first and the third row with black color and the second and fourth with white. Clearly, whenever you place a $L$-Shaped domino there, it will cover either $(\hbox{3 black position and 1 white})$ or $(\hbox{1 black and 3 white})$. However, the number of black and white position is same in the hole grid. Thus, $L$-Shaped domino must exist in pairs. To be more precise, for every domino covering $3$ black and $1$ white space, there must be another domino covering $1$ black and $3$ white positions. Thus, total number of $L$-Shaped domino must be even. But each $L$-Shaped domino has $4$ blocks in it. Thus total number of blocks that an even number of dominoes can cover will be a multiple of $4\times 2=8$. But total number of blocks in the grid is $44$ which is not a multiple of $8$. Hence, a $4\times 11$ board cannot be covered with $L$-shaped dominoes.

Comment: woah..Nice solution ! *and someone says he is bad in combi -_- *

Comment: @SunainaPati Well, I'm not as good as you :P Thanks though :D